# Can I make the Visual Studio (2008) editor keep my current line in the middle of the screen?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want my currently editing line to be in the middle of the screen.

Does anyone know if it's possible, and how?

Thanks, Tim

Comment: I can only just imagine how nausea-inducing it would surely be to have text *constantly* scrolling all around the screen, were this somehow configured.

Answer (score 8):

Not automatically, but you can assign

```
Edit.ScrollLineCenter
```

to a keyboard shortcut and press it whenever you think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

visual-studio by itself can't do that, sorry.